# How did the telephone work and what was its role in Einstein's God Model?

Tags: plot-device, einsteins-god-model

In the movie *[Einstein's God Model](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1773389/)* sometimes a rotary telephone was used to receive messages from the dead or to exit the Matrix.

Other times it seems that the telephone was not involved, such as when the Anesthesiologist entered the membrane / Matrix world.

Could someone clarify exactly what the role of the telephone was supposed to be and how it was supposed to be connected to the God Model (or whatever the proper name was for the machine / experiment)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question!  In the story, the process of contacting the afterlife (i.e. another membrane) is made in consecutive steps (i.e. injecting Ketamine, starting the machine, the membrane is contacted, the phone rings, etc.).  When the main character, Brayden is subjected to the process, he is given general anesthesia to avoid the seizures and brain trauma associated with the equipment.  This allows Dr. Mastenbrook to "crank up" the settings on the various components (infrasound, magnetic field, optical stimulator, etc.) to levels that would otherwise be lethal.  Because the levels are so high, things go terribly wrong before the process can ever reach the step where the phone rings.  Brayden's consciousness creates a quantum entanglement with the other membrane and he is transferred to another universe.  Hope this answers your question!

Philip T. Johnson (writer/director)

Comment: It's not everyday you get a writer/director replying on here. Many thanks! Great film!

Comment: Since this has been answered by the writer / director, I have mentioned it on [meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10472/143).

Comment: "Brayden's consciousness creates a quantum entanglement with the other membrane and he is transferred to another universe." I really hope this makes more sense in context, as I haven't seen the movie and it sounds a touch science-talk-handwavy.